# Получить выборку через отношения

Tags: php, laravel

можно ли получить выборку через отношения ?

К примеру

```
$hall = Hall::find($id);

return new HallResource($hall->load(['schedule_hall.programm.children.journal']));
```

Мне нужно к примеру  **select * from hall where id = 1 and programm day = 5**, только day нет в таблице hall , он в таблице programm (связь с ней через отношения hasmany)

Answer (score 1):

```
$hall=Hall::find($id)->days()->where('days',5)->first();
```

Comment: Работает, но дело в том что запись не одна, а если убираю ->first() и получаю ошибку HasMany::toArray(), подскажите ка исправить ?

Comment: Соответственно я дальше хочу получить связи return new HallResource($hall->load(['programm.children.journal']));

Comment: Ты можешь дальше строить запросы типы  where('new_field',$hall)...а потом преобразовывать данные. Лучше в моделе создай , то что нужно получать с базы, а потом с этими данными хоть на луну

Comment: Если использовать этот запрос, как избавиться от ошибки HasMany::toArray() ?

Comment: в конце добавь  get()

Comment: Спасибо, точно надо !!!